# Apache 2 Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, virtualhost, symlink

My apache server runs as user foo.

I have some Rails applications in /home/foo/app1 /home/foo/app2.
Each of them has an vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app1.foobar.com
    ServerAlias www.app1.foobar.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app1/current/public
    RailsEnv production
    <Directory /var/www/html/app1/current/public>
    AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a symlink in /var/www/html/app1 :

```
current -> /home/foo/app1/tmp_20102611
```

All file permissons are set correctly (user foo group foo), I can go through the filesystem from shell.

SELINUX is disabled

Distro is CentOs 5.5

Which the above symlink I get an 403 and an error entry in error_log

> Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:/var/www/html/app1/current

When I symlink my app in the subdir of /var/www/html instead of /home/foo it works.

How I can avoid this error still placing my app in my /home/foo directory ?

Comment: If I may suggest you read about SELinux on http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux. It would better to have SELinux running and just modify your file securities to better secure your linux machine.

Answer (score 8):

I had a very similar problem. Like you, I was unable to follow symlinks under my home directory even though I had the FollowSymlinks enabled plus I could ls around with my http user, but putting symlinks under /srv/http worked just fine... I fixed it by chmod'ing my home directory to be executable:

```
chmod +x /home/mgalgs
```

And that did it for me! Maybe try

```
chmod +x /home/foo/app1
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting the option

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

in your configuration. See the Documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options) for more details.

Comment: not so easy, my Apache has this option turned on in my global config. Thanks anyway

Comment: normally this gets set on a per directory base. can you us give the relevant configuration lines